# I can find multiple wi-fi networks but I can't find mine

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, atheros

I've searched through a few sites, I've done a few things and I can't find the solution to this problem.

As the title says, I can't connect to my wi-fi home network on my laptop using ubuntu 18.04 .
I can detect other networks, even a hotspot created by my phone, but I can't detect my network. I can detect and connect to my home wifi with my smartphone and on the same laptop on Windows 10 but not with Ubuntu.
So I wonder if the problem is related to Ubuntu or some drivers or something similar.
As far as I know, there aren't any drivers missing and everything is updated. Rebooting the router didn't work either.

> Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9377 802.11ac Wireless Network
>   Adapter (rev 31)

Would like to know what is wrong or if there is something missing.

(First question I ask here so take it easy on me.)

Answer (score 0):

https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/net-wireless-connect.html.en

«If the name of the network is not in the list, try clicking More to see if the network is further down the list. If you still do not see the network, you may be out of range, or the network might be hidden.»